Not correct reading in ADCs DACs integrated system
I made a ADCs board (AD7194) and DACs board (AD5689). Each DAC (separated ground) could output 0-5V, and Each ADC channel could measure 0-3.3V. I used a voltage divider network to turn 0-5V to 0-3.3V. The purpose of the ADCs is to measure each DAC channel output.
The DACs output could be connected in series (i.e. The first DAC Ground can be connected to the second DAC positive side). For example, two DACs could gives 0-10V in total. However, the output after the voltage divider didn't give correct values.
For be below graph, the voltage source can be thought as DAC. And the voltmeter can be thought as ADC. The middle part is the switch, which connect second DAC positive voltage to the first DAC ground. If I don't connect them, the two ADC values read the input voltage correctly.
However, if I close the switch to connect them, the output of the voltage divider (i.e. the ADC reading) would be incorrect. For example, DAC1 and DAC2 gives 4.4V, the upper voltage divider would become 2.1V(i.e. first ADC reading), and the lower become 2.8V. For the correct value which two DACs are not connected, both should gives 2.8V.
Things get more abnormal if I have 5 connected DAC if they are connected. If they are not connected, their reading after voltage divider network is correct. But once I connect them, each output after voltage divider have abnormal values.
I have stuck here for a while, and I think the problem are likely the voltage divider. Other less likely problems could be grounding problem as DACs ADCs system are two separated ground, the the DACs system itself have separated ground.


the two circuits in the diagram are separate even when the swith is closed

What voltages do you read on a DMM connected to the ADC inputs while the DACs are connected in series? Do you read the correct voltage difference between the two GND lines of the ADCs?

@Jens, yes, the DMM gives the expected and correct output for the DAC. The reading of ADC input (voltage to be measured) is also correct. The problem is likely come from the ADC. When the 5 voltage sources is disconnected, each ADC reading is correct. While they are connected, all ADC gone wrong.

I think we need a better schematic of the real circuit including all supply connections to understand the issue. The problem is outside of the currently shown picture.
